# Using @Sort annotation with List<Object>

Tags: java, hibernate

I can't find any information about that issue. 
Will such List be a sorted? 
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the Hibernate annotation `@Sort`?

Comment: I think he means hibernate. The question is tagged as hibernate.

Comment: Can you point us to where you find the reference (any reference at all) to @Sort?

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/news/sorting-collections-hibernate

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. List can not be sorted with @Sort annotation in hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Explanation from here: http://java.dzone.com/news/sorting-collections-hibernate

What if you want to control how null values are ordered so they come first rather than last? In Hibernate there are several ways you could do this. First, you could use the Hibernate-specific @Sort annotation to perform in-memory (i.e. not in the database) sorting, using natural sorting or sorting using a Comparator you supply.

@Sort allows providing your custom comparator `@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = EventCompator)`. Otherwise the list will be sorted according to natural order, i.e. you can model it without hibernate using `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: I understand this lines. But what if I add @Sort annotation to List<SomeObject> collection?